# Calling Java method by passing a vector in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

How would one call a Java method by passing a vector object in JNI (using C++)? I've something like this:

Java:

```
public void methodOne(int[] data) {
    ...
}
```

C++:

```
...
jMethodOne = env->GetMethodID(jActivityClass, "methodOne", "([I)V");
void mNativeMethod(std::vector<int> dataVector)
{
    // how to call method one by passing the vector? I've tried following way and I got SIGABRT error, even after converting dataVector to an int array
    env->CallVoidMethod(jObject, jMethodOne, dataVector);
}
```

I've tried the above
 and I got SIGABRT error, even after converting dataVector to an int array

Comment: So... what's the question?  Did you try it? What doesn't work?

Comment: The question is, as stated in the first line, is "How would one call a Java method by passing a vector object in JNI (using C++)?
Did I try? Yes sir, I did as stated in the second sentence - "I've something like this"
What doesn't work? As is in the comment, sir, I get SIGABRT. Did you read the question?

Comment: You provided some code that does that... did it work? If not, what happened? You probably have to adapt the `std::vector` to something Java understands.

Comment: Don't put critical error information in code comments, make sure the narrative of your question includes all the necessary information.

Comment: Do you think if it had worked I would be spending my time asking question here? "You probably have to adapt the std::vector to something Java understands" You'd think that I'd have figured that much out and tried it out. With all due respect, I don't think you are trying to help me out here. Please let someone with JNI experience to help me here.

Comment: You are making it really hard to help you by omitting critical information.  Post the _actual_ code that failed AFTER adapting vector to `int[]`.

Comment: Forget about the error, focus on the question - if there was a Java method that takes an array of int, and you want to call that method from C++ (and say you have a C++ vector or even a C++ array), how'd you do that? Any examples? Any links? And don't think that I've not already spent few hours trying different things and running into all kind of seg faults. Like I said, please let someone with JNI experience jump in and see if they could help. Thanks for trying

Comment: I don't understand the reluctance to show us how you adapted the vector to a `jIntArray`.  Check out this page: https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-pass-integer-array-from-c-to-java/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Doesn't look like it shows calling a Java method by passing an int array (it only shows returning an array). And, believe me I've copied pasted all the relevant code that I have and maybe the problem is exactly that - I've done enough like adapting the vector to jIntArray which I'm going to try next.

Comment: Scroll down about 3/4 of the page.  ***PASS INTEGER ARRAYS FROM C TO JAVA*** Example : Write a program that generates the first n Fibonacci numbers. Pass ‘n’ as an argument from Java to a native function in C that returns the Fibonacci numbers as an integer array.

Comment: That *returns* an array but not *pass* an array but it's okay I figure it out now. I had to do bunch of work to convert to `jint[]` and it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like this:

```
void mNativeMethod(std::vector<int> dataVector)
{
    unsigned long size = dataVector.size();
    jfloat outCArray[size];
    std::copy(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), outCArray);

    jfloatArray outJNIArray = jniEnv->NewFloatArray(size);
    jniEnv->SetFloatArrayRegion(outJNIArray, 0, size, outCArray);
    jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(jObject, jMethodOne, outJNIArray);
}
```